# CloudControl: Restart workers on deployment

Tags: php, worker, cloudcontrol

Is there any way to restart a worker when deploying. If the worker is not running start it while deploying.

The workers are registered in `Procfile`, but i always have to start them manually with an api request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cctrlapp APP_NAME deploy --restart-workers`, this will stop all running workers and start them again with the new deploy version.

But this doesn't start workers if they don't exist. This is tricky to automate because not all workers in the Procfile are long running workers and you could also have workers which are started multiple times.